# How much water in potato-leek soup (Vichyssoise)?

Tags: soup

Larousse De La Cuisine (American Edition) has the following recipe for vichyssoise:

- 250g leeks
- 250g potatos
- 50g butter
- 1.75L water
- 200mL crème fraîche

I was cooking 3 times as much soup, so I multiplied the amount of leeks, potatos, and butter by 3. However, 5.25L was just way too much. I ended up eyeballing it and using ~3L. Still, the end result was a bit too watery for me.

It seems that even the above recipe has too much water. Is this a typo?

Or was it in the scaling up? I can imagine that you do not simply multiply by 3, even if you use a bigger pot than you'd use for the non-scaled version.

Comment: Btw, I checked another edition of the book (a single volume edition, mine is multi-volume) and the recipe was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a typo but the recipe surprises me, traditionally (as far as a 100ish year old dish can be "traditional") vichyssoise would have chicken stock or seasoned milk as the liquid base.

For that quantity of potato and leek I would estimate 0.6->0.75L of liquid so it is possible it is a typo.